# Given $z_1, z_2$ prove that $4z^2_1+9z^2_2 = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to show that given $z_1 = 9 + 9i$  and $z_2=6-6i$,  $$4z_1^2+9z_2^2=0.$$

$$z_1 = 12.7(cos 45 + i sin 45)$$
$$z_2 = 8.5(cos 315 + i sin 315)$$

I changed the terms to polar form, applied De Moivre's Theorem, and got $4z^2_1+9z^2_2 = 50.8i-76.5i$, which is incorrect.

Comment: Could you work out your solution? Otherwise it is very hard to see where you went wrong.

Comment: Too lazy to check, but did you calculate the $\cos$ and $\sin$ on a calculator? If so, there's a high risk of a degrees-radians mixup.

Comment: @DanShved i didn't square r, should i delete the question?...

Comment: Also, even with De Moivre, there's no need to use approximate values written as decimal fractions. Write precise expressions, there's less of a chance to make a mistake that way.

Comment: @problematic agreed with Dan Shved; if you plug in $z_1 = 12.7(\cos(45)+i\sin(45))$ you will get the wrong answer

Comment: @graydad okay, 81(cos 90 + i sin 90)

Comment: @graydad De Moivre's Theorem? 45 x 2

Comment: @graydad Can you answer this? thanks .http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994567/find-critical-point-fx-y-8-2y32x3-3xy#994567

Comment: @problematic You are correct; nice use of DeMoivre's formula. Although I still think you should have 162 instead of 81 as a coefficient. Also my vector calc is too rusty for me too feel good about answering that question. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to know where is the mistake without seeing the computations.
The problem is good:
$z_1^2=81(1+i)^2=162i$, $z_2^2=36(1-i)^2=-72 i$, $4z_1^2+9z_2^2= 648i-648i=0$

Comment: i didn't square r...

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates $z_1$ should be $$9+9i = \frac{18}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) = \frac{18}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}\right)$$ and $z_2$ should be $$6-6i = \frac{12}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) = \frac{12}{\sqrt{2}}\left(e^{\frac{7i\pi}{4}}\right)$$ Does this agree with what you got? If not, try plugging these in and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This problem (should be) pretty straightforward, and I don't think you need De Moivre's theorem, either. Sometimes it helps to factor our similar terms, as I did in the last step, to check your progress.

$z_1=9+9i, \space z_2=6-6i$

$$\implies z_1^2=81+81i+81i+81i^2 = 81-81+(2\cdot81)i = (2\cdot81)i,$$
$$z_2^2=36-36i-36i+36i^2 =36-36-(2\cdot36)i=-(9\cdot8)i.$$

$$4z_1^2+9z_2^2\implies4(2\cdot81)i-9(9\cdot8)i \implies 8\cdot81i-8\cdot81i =0. $$